# Slow event processing in axon when using Postgres as event store

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, axon

I'm using Axon framework (4.3) in my spring boot (2.3.0) application and I've set a Postgres (9) db as event store through jpa. The database is only used as an event store and no other relations are persisted there. The db is also deployed in a dedicated VM.

After a year of the app being live, I started noticing extreme slowness on the level of event processing (slowing down the whole app).

Events were being dispatch and take a while to get handled.

The application is deployed across 4 instances and periodically restarted when we do rollouts. The event store is shared among all instances.

Multiple event processors are configured as an event tracking processor.

After trying multiple tricks like:

- Resetting processors
- Scaling application down to 1 instance
- Upgrading to latest axon version
- Upgrading to latest spring boot version
- Deleting events from postgres db
- Dropping all axon tables and starting from scratch

no progress was witnessed.

Only after restarting Postgres did the performance go back to normal and even faster.

What could be the explanation of this?

Comment: The fact that a Postgres restart solved your issue makes it feel to me it's not an Axon issue, but a Postgres issue. Perhaps there was some locking or vacuuming going wrong, but I am not a Postgres expert.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're running into [PostgreSQL's TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/storage-toast.html) approach here.
To describe it in short, PostgreSQL will move *any* BLOB/CLOB/LOB fields in an internal and private table and reference the data with an OID.

As Axon keeps generating events, you're thus not just growing the `domain_event_entry` table but also this internal table. It's the referencing, and thus the performed joins, that can become cumbersome. Especially if this private table isn't cleared.

Where it becomes more painful is the `token_entry` table. Every update on this, thus every time events are handled by a Streaming Event Processor, creates a new OID reference. Hence, you can quickly explode the table.

Your best solution is to entirely remove the "TOASTing" from your application for Axon's tables. AxonIQ's working on a blog for this, but in the meantime, [this blog](https://blog.trifork.com/2017/10/09/axon-postgresql-without-toast/) from 2017 might guide you on a solution. AxonIQ already has a sample on the dialect you'd need to set, which you can as part of the Saga sample [here](https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/tree/master/saga).

---

I stand corrected, AxonIQ already has that blog live.
You can find it [here](https://developer.axoniq.io/w/axonframework-and-postgresql-without-toast).

Comment: "Especially if this private table isn't cleared." do you mean here vacuumed? or deleting the old live tuples?

Comment: Is the slowness here from the large size of the toasted tables? or from the joins being done when populating the "token_entry" table for example?

Comment: Is there any reason why this is dialect and setup is not part of default autoconfiguration and behaviour?

Comment: Let me answer the questions one by one.

I believe that's the term in PostgreSQL, so yeah, vacuumed, Nader.

Comment: My hunch is that both the size as well as the joins cause the slowness, Nader. Regardless of whether it is one or the other, the suggested configuration wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Axon Framework aims to provide Spring and non-Spring specific auto-config. For Spring providing this out of the box would be relatively straightforward. For non-Spring users it's a bit more complex. It's not to say it will not be introduced, but there are more things to take care of with Axon. Especially with the shift we're seeing towards dedicated Event Store solutions, the priority of things like thus just changes. If you are up for a PR, that would be awesome and much appreciated, Vaelyr.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe having it inside the framework isn't necessarily needed as the config is very easy to do, but moving the guide from blog post to Axon reference docs would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Sounds like a fair recommendation to me, Vaelyr.